# LDAP Query to List All Groups User is a Member of?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

Given a username, how would I go about writing an LDAP query that will return all groups that the user is a member of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you on .NET 3.5 ??

If so, check out this excellent MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows the new feature for user and groups management in .NET 3.5.

In this case, you need a principal context (e.g. your domain):

```
PrincipalContext domainContext = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain");
```

and then you can pretty easily find the user:

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "username");
```

and the "UserPrincipal" object has a method called "GetAuthorizationGroups" which returns all groups the user is a member of:

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

// display the names of the groups to which the
// user belongs

foreach (Principal result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}", result.Name);
}
```

Pretty easy, huh?

It's a lot more work in .NET before 3.5, or in "straight" LDAP from some other language (PHP, Delphi etc.).

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Here is a another way to get the group information:

Make sure you add a reference for System.DirectoryServices.

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=YourOrganizationOU,DC=foo,DC=bar");

DirectoryEntry user = GetObjectBySAM("SomeUserName", root);

if (user != null)
{
  foreach (string g in GetMemberOf(user))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(g);
  }
}
```

The following methods get the user entry and return a list of strings which is the groups the user is a member of.

```
public List<string> GetMemberOf(DirectoryEntry de)
{
  List<string> memberof = new List<string>();

  foreach (object oMember in de.Properties["memberOf"])
  {
    memberof.Add(oMember.ToString());
  }

  return memberof;
}

public DirectoryEntry GetObjectBySAM(string sam, DirectoryEntry root)
{
  using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root, string.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", sam)))
  {
    SearchResult sr = searcher.FindOne();

    if (!(sr == null)) return sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
    else
      return null;
  }
}
```